# Virtualbox Freezes Entire Computer when starting any Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox, dkms

I have VirtualBox installed on Ubuntu 16.04 and was running 2 machines from there . First being Homestead and the second being a Windows 7 Machine .

Everything was working fine, until earlier today when I got an error about kernels not being installed . After a bit of searching I found the following solution online:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

Whenever I try start any of the machines, after the above commands, the entire PC freezes and nothing happens, and I have to do a hard reset.

I tried un-installing virtualbox and re-installing it, but it did not help. I am not to stressed about the Windows machine , but I am worried about the Homestead one ... I cannot lose that info that is on there :(

Edit : I normally start the Homestead machine through the command prompt using Vagrant . Using this method also freezes up the entire system ...

Comment: Check the allocated RAM size and processor number in your Virtualbox!

Comment: Hi George , Thank you for the reply . I have checked on the homestead machine and is still the same as it was before . 2 Gigs of ram allocated and 1 CPU.